# Permission issues while BCP out in Sybase 15.7

Tags: sybase, bcp

In Sybase 15.7, when data is bulk copied out using Sybase’s bcp utility, the output file generated is having permissions(Read/Write-able) by owner only .

How to resolve this issue this bcp will be called from js.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem with Sybase ASE15.7 and found the SOLUTION! (do not delete my post please!)

As from ASE15.7 ESD#4, the default security is stricter with BCP. There is a new BCP option "--filemode" which allows you to specify the permissions of your bcp out files.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check/change the [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) for the user that the database runs as.  This setting will affect what the default file permissions are for new files.

You should excersise caution with this, as expanding the permissions could allow a non-privledged user access to the data exported from your database.